# Neo4j BatchInserter count failure,How can i do?

Tags: neo4j

I am use the following code to batch insert  data into neo4j database, but after i run the code, the Cypher "match (n) return count(n)" return 0.I have try much times,but not success, Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

```
int denseNodeThreshold = GraphDatabaseSettings.dense_node_threshold.defaultValue();
    DatabaseLayout tempStoreDir = ((GraphDatabaseAPI)graphDb).databaseLayout();
    final FileSystemAbstraction fileSystem = new DefaultFileSystemAbstraction();
    batchInserter = BatchInserters.inserter(tempStoreDir, fileSystem, configuration(denseNodeThreshold));
    batchInserter.createDeferredSchemaIndex(personLabel).on("name").create();
    final ArrayList<Long> nodeIds = new ArrayList<>();
    //没有索引，通过Neo4j Desktop打开左侧没有 Node Labels和Relationship Types，有索引的情况下，count为0
    for(int i=0; i<1e5; i++){
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put( "name", UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
        long nodeId = batchInserter.createNode( properties, personLabel );
        nodeIds.add(nodeId);
    }
    final Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<1e3; i++){
        Long from = nodeIds.get((random.nextInt() % nodeIds.size() + nodeIds.size()) % nodeIds.size());
        Long to = nodeIds.get((random.nextInt() % nodeIds.size() + nodeIds.size()) % nodeIds.size());
        batchInserter.createRelationship( from, to, knows, null );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

You cannot use an in-process server as its files are deleted after each shutdown, which explains why the count is always 0 when you restart it.

On a side note, you should close the `BatchInserter` with a try-with-resources block to make sure the changes are flushed once you're done creating the nodes and relationships:

```java
try (BatchInserter batchInserter = BatchInserters.inserter(tempStoreDir, fileSystem, configuration(denseNodeThreshold))) {
   // [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the code and run it by your way.It still count failure.

Comment: The code can be found here.
https://github.com/pxfoost/neo4j-demo/blob/master/neo4j-demo/src/main/java/com/pxfoost/neo4jdemo/service/Service.java